# Text appears in a different box while hovering

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to get familiar with CSS Grid. Therefore I created the following piece of code ;)

I am looking for a solution for my hover effect. If I hover an image on the left side, the corresponding text should appear in the bigger right text field and disappear after the hover is over.

At the moment there is no communication between the divs.

I would be really thankful for any idea.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.box {
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;

}

.box .box {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.textInfo {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: row 2;
}

.pastries{
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: row 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: #fff0;
}

.cupcake {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row:  1;
  background: white url(../img/024-cupcake.png);
}

.cheeseCake {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
  background: white url(../img/014-cake.png);
}

.cookies {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
  background: white url(../img/028-cookie.png);
}

.caramel {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  background: white url(../img/034-honey.png);
}

.chocolate {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 3;
  background: white url(../img/029-chocolate-bar.png);
}

.applePie {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 3;
  background: white url(../img/007-pie.png);
}

.peanutButterCups {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 4;
  background: white url(../img/017-cracker.png);
}

.doughnut {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 4;
  background: white url(../img/035-doughnut.png);
}

.iceCream {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 5;
  background: white url(../img/030-ice-cream.png);
}

.croissant {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 5;
  background: white url(../img/023-croissant.png);
}

.box .cupcake,
.cheeseCake,
.cookies,
.caramel,
.chocolate,
.applePie,
.peanutButterCups,
.doughnut,
.iceCream,
.croissant {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #e8a4c9;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px;
}

.textInfo h2 {
  margin:0;
}

.innerText {
  margin: 10px;
}

h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

p {
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.textInfo:hover {
  background-color: #e8a4c9;
  color: #fff;
}

.item:hover {
  background-color: #e8a4c9;
}

.pastries {
  background-color: #fff0;
  color: #e8a4c9;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px;
}

.textInfo {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #e8a4c9;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 720px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  }

  .textInfo {
    grid-column: 1 / 5;
    grid-row: row 2;
  }

  .pastries{
      grid-column: 1 / 5;
      grid-row: row 1;
      display: grid;
      grid-gap: 10px;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      background-color: #fff0;
  }

  .cupcake {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row:  1;
  background: white url(../img/024-cupcake.png);
  }

  .cheeseCake {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
  background: white url(../img/014-cake.png);
  }

  .cookies {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
  background: white url(../img/028-cookie.png);
  }

  .caramel {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 1;
  background: white url(../img/034-honey.png);
  }

  .chocolate {
  grid-column: 5;
  grid-row: 1;
  background: white url(../img/029-chocolate-bar.png);
  }

  .applePie {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
  background: white url(../img/007-pie.png);
  }

  .peanutButterCups {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  background: white url(../img/017-cracker.png);
  }

  .doughnut {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2;
  background: white url(../img/035-doughnut.png);
  }

  .iceCream {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 2;
  background: white url(../img/030-ice-cream.png);
  }

  .croissant {
  grid-column: 5;
  grid-row: 2;
  background: white url(../img/023-croissant.png);
  }

  .box .cupcake,
  .cheeseCake,
  .cookies,
  .caramel,
  .chocolate,
  .applePie,
  .peanutButterCups,
  .doughnut,
  .iceCream,
  .croissant {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 35px;
  height: 30px;
  }

  .innerText {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 5px;
  }

}
```

```html
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="box textInfo"><h2>Please, select a category first!</h2>
          <div class="innerText innerText-cupCake"><h3>Cupcake</h3>
              <p>Ice cream fruitcake cotton candy. Fruitcake pudding gummi bears macaroon croissant dessert sweet roll. Jelly beans
                caramels chocolate cake bonbon liquorice soufflé soufflé sweet halvah.</p>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="box pastries">
            <div class="box item cupcake"></div>
            <div class="box item cheeseCake"></div>
            <div class="box item cookies"></div>
            <div class="box item caramel"></div>
            <div class="box item chocolate"></div>
            <div class="box item applePie"></div>
            <div class="box item peanutButterCups"></div>
            <div class="box item doughnut"></div>
            <div class="box item iceCream"></div>
            <div class="box item croissant"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your question/problem is not very clear. What text should appear where exactly?

Comment: Hey Helenesh, the text from:  

<div class="innerText innerText-cupCake">

At the moment it is static.

Comment: @JWhitemann "If you hover a left div the right div should change background.." That's the case?

Comment: No. If I hover the pastries items (for example box item cupcake), there should be text (innerText innerText-cupCake) displayed in the right text field.